# Find common subsets between "big" sets

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, subset

So, I have a file that contains about 13000+ rows. Each row has a list of destinations separated by the char ";". I need to find between all those lists of destinations the 10 most common subsets (ignoring empty set or sets containing only 1 destination) between all the destinations, and the amount of times this subsets appear on the data:

An example may make this easier to understand:

This would be the file (each letter represents a destination)

```
A;B;C;D
A;B
A;B;C;D;E
A;B;C;D;E;F;G
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;L
C;G;B
K;H
```

So, the most common subsets of destinations together would be:

```
1. A;B : 5
2. A;C : 4
3. A;D : 4
4. A;B;C : 4
5. A;B;C;D : 4
6. A;E : 3
7. A;B;C;D;E : 3
8. B;C;D;E : 3
9. C;D;E : 3
10. A;B;C;D;E;F : 2
```

This problem seems very complex to me, I think it would be easier to solve it by limiting the size of the subsets to *n* (or a fixed number like 3).

Any ideas on how to solve it? I think I need something like FPGRowth but without the Association Rule generated.

Thanks!

Comment: How many destinations on each row, and how many distinct destinations are there?

Comment: Looks like a map-reduce job

Comment: If I understand this correctly you'd need to count to occurrences of each possible subset of destinations in that list of sets you've got. If I'm right this is `O(2^n)`, unless there's some way to do this I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this with one loop:
You have to generate a hashmap for saving the results...
you can give every destination a unique prime number and multiplicate the prime numbers of one line. the result is the key of the hashmap. if the key does not exist, you have to add it with a value of 1. If it exists, you can increase the value. This is called "Integer factorization". At the end you have to find the highest value number of your hashmap.

> (hint: save the destination name also in the value of the hashmap,
> then you do not have to recalculate the number to the destinations)
>
> (2nd hint: remember the highest number and hashkey, so you don't have
> to search at the end for the highest number and key...)

EDIT: for the combinations like A;B;C =>A;B and also B;C you can use 2 for loops to go through the line

Comment: I'm not sure, if it was "Prime decomposition" or "Integer factorization" BR